# CTS installing problemand

Tags: android

This section describe the procedure to run CTS on any platform.

```
* Pre-requisites
      o Download and extract (untar) the CTS package from http://dl.google.com/dl/android/cts/android-cts-2.2_r4-x86.zip
      o Download and extract (untar) Google Android SDK from http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r06-linux_86.tgz
      o NOTE: Only the SDK mentioned on the above link will work with CTS. 
* Setup an ADB connection between Host and platform as mentioned in ADB section above.
* Setup your platform to run the accessibility tests:
      o adb install -r android-cts/repository/testcases/CtsDelegatingAccessibilityService.apk
      o On the device enable Settings > Accessibility > Accessibility > Delegating Accessibility Service 
* Launch the CTS.
      o Edit android-cts/tools/startcts to point SDK_ROOT to android sdk installation location.
      o Run ./tools/startcts
      o On CTS prompt check the available plans
```

---

I'm following the above steps but I'm struck in the below step
Launch the CTS.(mainly here)
          o Edit android-cts/tools/startcts to point SDK_ROOT to android sdk installation location.
          o Run ./tools/startcts
          o On CTS prompt check the available plans

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All [Edit android-cts/tools/startcts to point SDK_ROOT to android sdk installation location] is saying is to edit startcts and point SDK_ROOT to the correct folder where you installed the Android SDK. If your using linux you can use vi or pico to edit the file. Just change to that directory and type:

```
vi startcts
OR
pico startcts
```

Find the line in the file that contains SDK_ROOT, and change its value to wherever you installed the Android SDK.